# How to deploy a windows phone 8 app developed on VS 2013 2RC, windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile, windows-8.1

**Situation:** I am trying to develop and deploy a windows phone 8.0 app using *C#* and *XAML*. To do so, first I installed *Windows 8.1 Pro* and *Visual Studio 2013 Express with update 2 RC*. I developed a simple Windows Phone 8.0 app and was able to test it using emulator with no problems. I have updated *Zune* and *Microsoft Windows Phone app* installed (if the matter at all) .*Zune* does not detect the phone but *Microsoft Windows Phone app* does.

**Problem:** I want to test it on a phone with following specs:

- **Model:** Nokia Lumia 520
- **Software windows:** 8.0
- **Screen resolution:** 480x800

But I have problem with unlocking the phone. My procedure:

- I connect the mobile phone using a USB cable
- Unlock mobiles phone's screen lock.
- Started *Windows Phone Developer Regsitration*
- First I got: *Status: Identified Windows Phone 8 device. Click the Register button to unlock the phone.*
  [image]
- I click register and enter my Microsoft account credentials.
- I get logged in successfully.
- Then I have: Status: Trying to detect Windows Phone device connected to the PC. (before logging in to Microsoft account, Windows Phone was detected)[image]
- Then I have *Status: Unable to connect to a phone. For Windows Phone 7 phones make sure the Zune software is running and the Zune recognizes your phone. For Windows Phone 8 phones make sure that the Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport (IPOverUsbSvc) service is running.* (**I have checked the service is running**).[image]

**Question:** How to test and deploy a *Windows Phone 8.0* app, using Desktop *Windows 8.1 Pro* and *VS 2013 Express*? Do I have the complete and correct set to do so?

Comment: I heard there is occasionally a bug that first attempt fails, but it works on retrying a second time. You are doing everything correctly, and you don't need to worry about Zune. It's only for WP7 devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do have the requirements to deploy to a WP8 device. Just forget about zune as it is only needed for WP7 devices. Here are something you might want to check:

- You have a valid MS developer account and didn't reach the limit of unlocked devices
- The date/time is correct in both PC and Phone
- The phone is recognized by the OS and visible in Windows explorer

You might also want to try reloading the IPOverUsb service

Comment: I have checked all except the first. How to check if my Microsoft account has reached the limit to unlock devices, if no how to do it?

Comment: Log in to your dev dashboard and from there go to `Account` then `Phones`. You can then see how much phones you can unlock and what phones have you unlocked so far.

Comment: That was my problem, my Microsoft account was not reached to unlock level.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question, but I faced this problem today and found a different reason and solution.

The reason this happened on my device was because my phone's name was the same as an older device I had unlocked.

One of the requirements mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx states that phone names should be unique.

I renamed my phone and tried again and this time it unlocked my phone!